# Segmentation fault (core dump) in c

Tags: c, csv, strtok

I have a code which will read a csv file and save the data in the buffer. But i am getting segmentation fault core dump as the status error.

The contents of csv files  are

```
TimeStamp   BlockSeqNum SeqNum  X-axis  Y-axis  Z-axis
4294967295  0   0   27  20  -4
4294967295  0   1   48  11  -13
4294967295  0   2   45  0   -7
4294967295  0   3   38  -9  -2
4294967295  0   4   34  -42 -28
4294967295  0   5   -29 35  -35
4294967295  0   6   -3  -46 0
4294967295  0   7   0   2   -10
4294967295  0   8   6   113 -32
4294967295  0   9   -4  20  27
4294967295  0   10  -14 -15 -19
4294967295  0   11  23  51  -19
4294967295  0   12  10  34  1
4294967295  0   13  -7  -2  15
4294967295  0   14  13  -5  -30
4294967295  0   15  -24 30  51
4294967295  0   16  -18 39  -45
```

My code to read the and parse the file is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



struct pattern_buffer {    //structure to store the contents of csv files 
    unsigned int x[1024];
    unsigned int y[1024];
    unsigned int z[1024];

}Data_buffer;

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    char *record,*line;
    int x1=0,y1=0,z1=0,linecount=0; //linecount is used to check weather 1024 rows have been read or not

    int n=0;


    FILE *fstream = fopen("files.csv","r");
    if(fstream == NULL)             //check file 
    {
        printf("\n inside .so \n unable to open csv files \n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n Sensor values are \n");

    line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream);  //skip first line (weather it will skip the first line

    while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL   &&  linecount<1024)
    {
        record=strtok(line,",");  //skip first column
        while(record!= NULL)
        {   
            //record=strtok(NULL,",");   //skip second column
            record=strtok(NULL,",");     //skip third column
            record=strtok(NULL,",");      //get x axis     
            Data_buffer.x[x1++]=atoi(record);
            record=strtok(NULL,",");         //get y axis     
            Data_buffer.y[y1++]=atoi(record);
            //record=strtok(NULL,",");        //get z axis     
            Data_buffer.z[z1++]=atoi(record);

        }
        linecount++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So please specify me weather my logic is correct for skipping first line and reading the csv values .

Comment: Note: there are no comma's in your CSV example. And `-4`is not a valid value for an `unsigned int`.

Comment: No actually it is a  copy of a csv file . it has commas ,  not displayed

Comment: i have used now signed int but still not able to get out put, Same error

Comment: Why don't you use `struct pattern_buffer { 
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;
}Data_buffer[1024];` ; keeping the related `{x,y,z}` together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , i have found the solution for this problem .

i  have not included  in the header file so strtok was not able to parse the token for me. i have checked the value of record while debugging but the record value was zero . so when i researched a lot i came to know that i have not included  which was causing me error .